# Remove old kernels with security implications / vulnerabilities

Tags: linux, security, linux-kernel, package-management

Some scanning tools (Qualsys, Sentinel, etc) detect installed old kernels and will report them as problems if those kernel versions have vulnerabilities. Is there a way to remove them *if* they have vulnerabilities?

I think I understand the rationale for the scanners -- having it installed makes it slightly easier for someone with access to boot the server into an old kernel and exploit a vulnerability. And while I'm not convinced that's a super-likely risk, I will admit that I've never had to roll back a kernel version, and keeping the old kernels installed is mostly for peace of mind, to know that's a viable option (for me).

But given the existence of tool options `yum update --security`, it would be nice if I could do something like `package-cleanup --oldkernels --security` to ask Linux to remove any kernels that are installed and have reported vulnerabilities.

I've done a little web searching to see if anyone has a way to do this, and I haven't seen anything -- not in the default tooling, not even something like a hand-rolled script. So, out of curiosity, does anyone have a solution for this? Or have you looked into it and decided it's not worth the effort?